# Encrypted key unauthorized for continuous deployment Travis → Heroku

Tags: heroku, meteor, travis-ci

I'm trying to configure [CoinsManager](http://www.coinsmanager.com/) so that [the alpha version](http://alpha.coinsmanager.com/) gets auto-deployed after Travis Continuous Integration.

Here is our **.travis.yml** file:

```yml
language: node_js
node_js:
- '0.10'
before_install:
- make install
services:
- mongodb
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  app: coinsmanager
  api_key:
    secure: "FjcbJdgcB1IIug3Qf5oFlF5PHW8LYnIUJCSUEz7GI5i6tVvtye1UvqkA12BP+//u3rtPcO3d33rjNY5/qvIRIdJ/wMKACAHdzRa8jWge2dxW7filynF6LVsh5ezwr7Sq/MgNwvqQcRp7eQNsOlBzdZRyQYE0VAa4fAD1+SZPnWQ="
  on:
    all_branches: true
after_deploy:
- "cd app/client/compass && compass compile && cd -"
- "cd app/ && meteor reset"
- restart
```

The problem is Travis reporting [the following error](https://travis-ci.org/CoinsManager/CoinsManager/builds/19471834):

```
Expected(200) <=> Actual(401 Unauthorized)
body: "{\"id\":\"unauthorized\",\"error\":\"Invalid credentials provided.\"}" (wrong API key?)
failed to deploy
```

But I did exactly like [the doc](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/) recommended

```
$ travis encrypt $(heroku auth:token) --add deploy.api_key
```

I also tried slighly different cases (with or without dash an double quotes), as suggested [in that Github issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1991#issuecomment-35853156).

I'm not sure where the problem comes from: Travis? Heroku?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem.

We have the upstream repo at **CoinsManager/CoinsManager**, which I forked at **Fandekasp/CoinsManager**. And when running travis encrypt, travis is getting the repo name from my origin remote, instead of querying the heroku git repo.

Therefore, I needed to specify the correct repo as follow:

```
$ travis encrypt -r CoinsManager/CoinsManager $(heroku auth:token) --add deploy.api_key
```

Comment: can you look at my build [here](https://travis-ci.org/AfolabiOlaoluwa/LawVille/builds/166266612). What am I missing? I have tried virtually everything you did mention in your question and your accepted answer too, but still didnt work. If I specify the exact answer you provided I get [this](https://travis-ci.org/AfolabiOlaoluwa/LawVille/builds/166261619)

Comment: I fixed it. Am missing a line in my `deploy script` being app name. I did run `setup heroku --org --force` and that line was added by responding to the prompt correctly. Thanks

Comment: How do I instruct my `.travis.yml` file to use a specific bundler just as we specify program version?