# How can I share the travis-heroku API key to others?

Tags: heroku

I'm using now use **travis-heroku** with my team.
But my **API key** doesn't allow my team members to pass the travis test.

How can I **share** travis-heroku API key with my team member?
Or are there any solution for this?

here's my partial `.travis.yml`

```
deploy:
provider: heroku
app:my-project-dev
api_key:
    secure: [my api code]
on:
    all_branches: true
```

I'm waiting for your help. Thank you **:)**

Comment: Now, my API key doesn't allow my team members to *deploy on heroku

Answer (score 1):

`body: "{\"id\":\"unauthorized\",\"error\":\"Invalid credentials provided.\"}" (wrong API key?)
failed to deploy`

You have to denote owner/repo when create heroku api key
$ travis encrypt -r [owner]/[repo] $(heroku auth:token)

it was referenced by
[Encrypted key unauthorized for continuous deployment Travis → Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978260/encrypted-key-unauthorized-for-continuous-deployment-travis-%E2%86%92-heroku)