# How to input heroku credentials in Travis Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, travis-ci

Am working Ruby on Rails site, and I have implemented Travis CI with it and pushed to to GitHub, so as to Test my build before pushing to Heroku.

When Travis parsed my github source code, I get an error asking me to input my `Heroku Credentials` before Travis can push to Heroku.

**What I want to do**

> How do I pass in my heroku credentials to Travis as requested without the >risk of putting it on version control?

Here is the Build on Travis: https://travis-ci.org/AfolabiOlaoluwa/LawVille/jobs/166099588

**.travis.yml**

```
language: ruby 
rvm:
- 2.2.4
env:
  global:
  - secure: {{ I have my travis encrypted key here }}
  - secure: {{ I another travis encrypted key here }}
  - DB=sqlite
  - DB=mysql
  - DB=postgresql
  - secure: {{ I have another travis encrypted key here }}
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: {{ I have HEROKU API KEY encrypted by travis here  }}
script:
- RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
- bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
before_script:
- mysql -e 'create database strano_test'
- psql -c 'create database strano_test' -U postgres
after_success:
- gem install heroku
- yes | ruby ./config/initializers/travis_deployer.rb
- git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:lawville.git
- heroku keys:clear
- yes | heroku keys:add
- git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from @andresk above is very useful, but encrypting the api-key only didnt work for me as you could see from our comments/correspondence.

What worked for me was, running `setup heroku --org --force` from the root of my app inside terminal and I followed the prompt to get my Travis file having the correct deploy script.

**Note**: the `--force` command is to force script written on the already existing `.travis.yml` file.

After responding to the prompts, my deploy script became:

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: encrypted_key_was_written_here
  app: lawville # being app name on heroku which am deploying to.
  on:
    repo: AfolabiOlaoluwa/LawVille # GitHub Repo
```

That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually push to heroku on `after_success`. Just having the `deploy` with your encrypted credentials is enough to automatically deploy after the build. So try removing the `after_success` commands and everything should work.

For more information, check [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku)

If you need to store your credentials to be used on Travis, you can add secure environment to Travis. Go to `More options > Settings` there you can add the credentials as environment variables. Just make sure `Display value in build log` is set as off

Comment: deploy failed with this error `body: "{\"id\":\"unauthorized\",\"error\":\"Invalid credentials provided.\"}" (wrong API key?)
failed to deploy`. Bet I did encrypt my Heroku API Key and attached to delpoy script as well

Comment: How did you encrypt your api key?

Comment: If you can't make it work this way, you can add heroku credentials as travis secure environment variables, I'll edit my answer to show how to do it

Comment: I did run this `travis encrypt $(heroku auth:token) --add deploy.api_key` and it added encrpted api-key. but failed still. you can check out my travis file here https://github.com/AfolabiOlaoluwa/LawVille/blob/master/.travis.yml. You can also check m Travis Build #22 and #23 here https://travis-ci.org/AfolabiOlaoluwa/LawVille/builds/166254262, https://travis-ci.org/AfolabiOlaoluwa/LawVille/builds/166256147

Comment: Hum it should be alright then. You sure the `heroku auth:token` returns a valid api key?

Comment: I have tried supporting question and the answers from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978260/encrypted-key-unauthorized-for-continuous-deployment-travis-%E2%86%92-heroku) since its my new problem, but still didnt work.